Could not find [SOME_PACKAGE] Searched in the following locations https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/
So I have a flutter project and I added the flutter_contacts to my pobspec.yaml and rebuild the app. few lines of output error:
Launching lib\main.dart on PHONE in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_contacts'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_contacts:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-7.4.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.1/gradle-7.4.1.jar
   > Could not find gradle-settings-api-7.4.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-settings-api:7.4.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-settings-api/7.4.1/gradle-settings-api-7.4.1.jar
   > Could not find lint-model-30.4.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.4.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/30.4.1/lint-model-30.4.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-7.4.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.4.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.4.1/builder-7.4.1.jar

Problem
The problem is that flutter can not access the dl.google.com to download the needed packages.
but in this output of pinging dl.google.com in terminal (project direcorty) we clearly see that dl.google.com is reachable:
 ping dl.google.com

Pinging dl.google.com [142.250.184.238] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.250.184.238: bytes=32 time=119ms TTL=51
Reply from 142.250.184.238: bytes=32 time=115ms TTL=51
Reply from 142.250.184.238: bytes=32 time=129ms TTL=51
Reply from 142.250.184.238: bytes=32 time=119ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 142.250.184.238:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 115ms, Maximum = 129ms, Average = 120ms

I know that this is a network issue and I had similar problems. usually they solve with a proxy but I don't know whats wrong in this one.
What I have tried that might work in other cases
I tried opening links in browser and I can access dl.google.com and every path mentioned in the error. but I can not download these package from Android Studio or terminal (from the project directory).
these are the things I'v tried:

Adding the url to the maven repositories
Changing DNS
Using VPN over PC and using proxy over gradle or Android Studio
using another internet connection with different ISP


Removing build cache fixed my problem.

Delete everything in C:\Users\{USERNAME}\.gradle\caches
Going to Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches and choosing Clearing file system cache and Local History and Delete embedded browser engine cache and cookies
flutter clean in project directory
make sure you use a good network connection, then flutter run in project directory
I needed to remove the proxy I had set for android studio using this link

